# Windows cannot access Network Error on Standard Account

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

I have a problem on accessing the network on a standard account. It is working on my administrator account, but it is not working on the standard account. How can I fix this?

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: WHAT “problem” are you having? Exactly.

Comment: @Appleoddity windows cannot access \\computer-name. Error code: 0x80070035. The screenshot didn't show in my post. Sorry.

Comment: Are these computers part of a domain? Are you logging in with a domain or local account? Have you tried typing in the specific share you want to access in file explorer or on the run command line? `\\computer-name\share-name`?

Comment: Are you able to `net use * \\computer-name\IPC$`? Maybe some overzealous security policy restricted that special share.

Comment: @Appleoddity it is just a local account. I have two accounts. A administrator and a standard account. It works fine on the administrator.

Comment: @grawity should I use cmd for that? Sorry. I'm just a noob. "System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open Command prompt as administrator on the target and execute: `reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\LanmanWorkstation /v AllowInsecureGuestAuth /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f` 
Then restart it. Your problem should be fixed after that.

However this will reduce your system security and you would be rather better off to just continue using it with an adminstrator account.

Please see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019/guest-access-in-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-and-windows-ser

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your drive is shared

1. Right click the drive on the targeted computer that you are to visit and choose *Properties*.
2. Navigate to *Sharing* tab. If you see that the network path here says Not Shared, then click *"Advanced Sharing..."*
3. Tick the box for Share this folder and then please make sure the the Share name is correct. Then click Apply and OK to save the change and exit.
4. Then on the host computer press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the run command. Type the name of the folder in the search box and hit Enter. You should be able to access to this folder correctly now.

If this does not fix it then on the Advance sharing tab click "permissions" and change the permissions

Comment: Still not working. Error: "You can't access this shared folder because your organization's security policies block unauthenticated guest access."

Comment: I just edited it, check the part after step 4

Comment: Still not working. Btw, I'm using a standard account when I encounter this error but whenever I use my administrator account, it all works fine.

Comment: what version of windows is the target device running

Comment: Windows 10. Is there a way or should I just reformat it again?

Comment: @helper if you’re going to direct someone to reduce the security of their computer, especially in what appears to be a business setting, at least indicate that so they can make an informed decision. There is not enough information provided in the question to make a determination that this change is needed - and it most likely is not.

Comment: I have identified your issue. open Command prompt as administrator on the target and execute: "reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\LanmanWorkstation /v AllowInsecureGuestAuth /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f" (ignore quotes). Then restart it. Your problem should be fixed after that. However this will reduce your system security and you would be rather better off to just continue using it with an adminstrator account

Comment: @Appleoddity Sorry I forgot to add the warning. I have included it now.

Comment: @Appleoddity The symptoms are the same as at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019/guest-access-in-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-and-windows-ser

Comment: @helper then you need to include the relevant link, as you have, that specifically points out that this has been disabled “since Windows 2000” and multiple warnings about this not being a recommended nor secure thing to do. It’s not necessary.

Comment: @helper it worked! Thank you :)